# Show that $|\int_a^b f dg | \le \|f\|_{\infty} \|g\|$

Tags: measure-theory, inequality, bounded-variation, stieltjes-integral

The following is from Bruckner's Real Analysis :

[image]

I could make a rigorous argument for items (a) and (b), but although intuitively item (c) seems to be reasonable but I cannot make a **rigorous** proof for that. Please help, thanks!

Comment: It is enough to show that the right hand side is greater or equal than the finite sums approximating the left hand side. Maybe you should write the proof you are not sure is rigorous enough and we could try to help you fix it or allay your doubts.

Comment: @tomasz, yes that's my intuition but I want a make a rigorous proof!

Comment: How is that not rigorous?

Comment: @tomasz, the only idea I have is that the lhs is \le 'max' of f which is (?) same as norm of f, then it remains |\int dg| which is upper-limit of BV-norm of g (?)

Comment: You should spell out the definitions of all the notions involved. As far as I can see, it's basically just that and triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in exercise 12:8.2, $f \in \mathcal{C}[a,b]$.

Given any partition of $[a,b]$, say $ a= x_0 <x_1 < \cdots <x_n =b$, and let  $t_1,t_2, \dots t_n $ satisfy $x_{i-1} \leq t_i \leq x_i$, for all $i =1, \dots, n$.  Then, we have
\begin{align*} 
\left | \sum_{i=1}^n f(t_i) (g(x_i) -g(x_{i-1}) \right | &\leq \sum_{i=1}^n |f(t_i)| | (g(x_i) -g(x_{i-1})| \leq  \\ 
&\leq \|f\|_\infty\sum_{i=1}^n |(g(x_i) -g(x_{i-1})|\leq  \|f\|_\infty V(g,[a,b])= \|f\|_\infty \|g\|
\end{align*}

So
$$ \left | \int_a^b f dg    \right|= \left | \lim_{\Delta(P)\to 0}  \sum_{i=1}^n f(t_i) (g(x_i) -g(x_{i-1})   \right| = \lim_{\Delta(P)\to 0} \left |  \sum_{i=1}^n f(t_i) (g(x_i) -g(x_{i-1})   \right| \leq  \|f\|_\infty \|g\|$$

Comment: Thanks a lot :)